# Farcaster Frames: Stopping a Frame after a Specific Number is Inputted

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, cryptocurrency, farcaster

I have a working Frame that allows a user to input a number in the text field and when they click submit, the next frame shows up telling them whether the number is too high or too low. I'm using frog.fm to help build this.

I want to know how I can capture the text input so that the game will end for everyone permanently once someone has guess the right number. I aslo want to lock a specific user based on their account ID from playing if they have guessed more than 3 times per 24 hours with a timer showing when their next 3 guesses unlocks.

Thanks!

I tried looking at the farcaster documentation but couldn't find info on how to do this type of backend logic.

Comment: Like Express.js (a web framework for Node.js), Django (a web framework for Python), or Flask (another web framework for Python).